# select from table a where record is not in table b and table c

Tags: sql

select from table a where record is not in table b and table c

i have tried somtihing like this

```
    select a.* from table a
left outer join b on b.index=a.index
left outer join c on c.index=a.index
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `b.index` and `c.index` are columns in the respective tables.

```
select a.* from table a
    left outer join b on b.index=a.index
    left outer join c on c.index=a.index
WHERE b.index IS NULL
AND c.index IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a 
WHERE a.`index` NOT IN (SELECT `index` FROM b) 
AND a.`index` NOT IN (SELECT `index` FROM c);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select * 
from table_a a 
where a.index not in (select b.index from table_b b) 
and a.index not in (select c.index from table_c c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your query gives you all records in a.  All you need to do now is add a `where` clause:

```
select a.* from table a
left outer join b on b.index=a.index
left outer join c on c.index=a.index
where b.index is null and c.index is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an exception join instead :

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLE A
    LEFT EXCEPTION JOIN B ON B.INDEX=A.INDEX
    LEFT EXCEPTION JOIN C ON C.INDEX=A.INDEX
```